# Can I start a foregrouond task in FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, foreground-service

I want to start a long proccess (say upload a file) by receiving a notification from Firebase. I don't want to start a new foreground service but I want to handle the upload in the same class like below:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        final String title=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        final String tag = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        if (tag.equals("start")) {
            startUpload(title,body);
        }
    }
}


public void startUplaod(String title,String body){
    ShowNotification(title,body);
    // and start upload
}

public void ShowNotification(String title,String text){
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
}
}
```

When I send a notification to the running device, sometimes I receive the target file on my server and sometimes not! The notification is not sticky and I am not sure if the upload task is being done or not? I guess that there is a limitation in time (may be some seconds) to finish the task and after that time the uplaod fails.

Is there any limitation to start a long task within the **FirebaseMessagingService** class? In other word can **startForeground** force the **FirebaseMessagingService** to start a foreground task for a long time?

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: There was no way. There is a time limit to accomplish the task. @user60108

Answer (score 3):

- For all messages where onMessageReceived is provided, your service should handle any message within 20 seconds of receipt (10 seconds on Android Marshmallow). The time window may be shorter depending on OS delays incurred ahead of calling onMessageReceived. After that, various OS behaviors such as Android O's background execution limits may interfere with your ability to complete your work.
- Can you use JobIntentService or WorkManager to upload task, I make a sample download image when received a notification.

  ```
  class ImageDownloadPushService : JobIntentService() {

  override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
      val bitmap = downloadImage("url")
      Log.e("ImageDownload", "$bitmap")
  }

  private fun downloadImage(address: String?): Bitmap? {
      // Convert string to URL
      val url = getUrlFromString(address)
      // Get input stream
      val inputStream = url?.let { getInputStream(it) } ?: return null
      // Decode bitmap
      // Return bitmap result
      return decodeBitmap(inputStream)
  }


  private fun getUrlFromString(address: String?): URL? {
      return try {
          URL(address)
      } catch (e1: Throwable) {
          null
      }
  }

  private fun getInputStream(url: URL): InputStream? {
      var inputStream: InputStream?
      // Open connection
      val conn: URLConnection
      try {
          conn = url.openConnection()
          conn.connect()
          inputStream = conn.getInputStream()
      } catch (e: IOException) {
          inputStream = null
      }

      return inputStream
  }

  private fun decodeBitmap(inputStream: InputStream): Bitmap? {
      var bitmap: Bitmap?
      try {
          // Turn response into Bitmap
          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
          // Close the input stream
          inputStream.close()
      } catch (e: IOException) {
          bitmap = null
      }

      return bitmap
  }

  companion object {
      private const val JOB_ID = 101
      fun enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent) {
          enqueueWork(context, ImageDownloadPushService::class.java, JOB_ID, work)
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- In onMessageReceived()

  ```
  override fun onMessageReceived(context: Context, remoteMessage: ToastRemoteMessage) {
       ImageDownloadPushService.enqueueWork(context, Intent())
  }
  ```

Comment: isn't starting a foreground service counted as handling a FCM message?

Comment: shouldn't, Should use background services, because you can receive a notification when app closed.